# How to using function postgres in UnitTest when using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, unit-testing

I have a function auto generate student_no using PostgreSQL. It working perfect when I use it in Postgres and Spring boot. But I have a problem when I use it in unit tests. In Postgres when I use the following command:

```
Insert into students(firstName,lastName,age) 
values ('Nguyen','Tran',12)
```

in database student_no auto generator look like "28372". It is the same with Spring boot. When I call method: `studentRepository.save(student)` it autogenerates student_no. But when I the following UnitTest:

```
@Slf4j
public class StudentTest {

      @Mock
      private StudentRepository studentRepository;

      @Test
      public void testGenerateStudentBooking_validRequest() {
         Student student = new Student("Nguyen","Tran",23);
         Student student = studentRepository.save(student);        
      }           
}
```

When I save and debug, student_no isn't generated. I can't understand why?

class Student:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Student {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Integer age;
  private String student_no;
}
```

StudentRepository

```
public inteface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository(Student,Integer) {
     Student findStudentByStudentNo(String StudentNo);
}
```

Student test

```
@Slf4j
public class StudentTest {

      @Mock
      private StudentRepository studentRepository;

      @Test
      public void testGenerateStudentBooking_validRequest() {
         Student student = new Student("Nguyen","Tran",23);
         Student student = studentRepository.save(student);  
         //Student.studentNo is null :(

         Student student1 = studentRepository.findStudentByStudentNo(student.getStudentNo);   
      }           
}
```

if possible how can I tell hibernate that booking_no will be automatically generated and hibernate will not do anything with it. Or in other words how to automatically generate booking_no using the function in Postgres when using UnitTest.

Comment: why do you need `student_no`? for assert statement? and also why don't you use `H2` in memory database for test cases

Comment: I can't using H2 because my project using postgresSql. I using student_no because i i have method find Student by student_no

Comment: i suggestion to use `H2` database just only for test case

Comment: Thanks you for suggestion. But function write in Postgres and trigger by Postgres. It working success , only Unit Test can't work. I don't think change Db good idea.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your problem

1. You can use `H2` in memory database for integration testing, so you don't need to mock `StudentRepository`
2. Second way is mocking the `StudentRepository` the one you are following now.

The problem in second approach is you need to define the stubbing for mocked objects saying that whenever `StudentRepository.save()` method is called return student object with randomly generated `id`

```
 @Slf4j
 public class StudentTest {

  @Mock
  private StudentRepository studentRepository;

  @Test
  public void testGenerateStudentBooking_validRequest() {
     Random random = new Random();
     when(this.studentRepository(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
          .thenReturn(new Student("Nguyen","Tran",23,random.nextInt(900) + 100 ));
   //random.nextInt(900) + 100   will generate a random integer from 0 to 899, then add 100
     Student student = new Student("Nguyen","Tran",23);
     Student student = studentRepository.save(student);
```

You can also use `ThreadLocalRandom` to generate random int value between 100(including) and 1000 (excluding)

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 1000);
```